# how to check values exists using array of values in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have an array like this

`let arr = [a,b,c]`

and database like this

> {val:a},{val:b}

I want to know that document with val=c is not in the collection

If you dont understand, please ask, instead of downvoting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asssuming you have a collection with docs as {val:"a"} ...
You could do something as follow :

https://mongoplayground.net/p/iI6-cFB-89v

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "vals": {
        "$addToSet": "$val"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "missingValues": {
          "$setDifference": [
            [
              "a",
              "b",
              "c"
            ],
            "$vals"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

It will return a list of document (since i used aggregation) with a single document containing a "missingValues" field with the list of values not matched in any doc of the collection.